# How to trigger a reactor if there is a change in the grain in saltstack?

Tags: salt-stack

**Usecase**- I have a grain value say `os_family` and this family gets updated using some automated script in the backend, I want to detect this change and trigger a custom reactor state on this change.

**Problem-** I have added the reactor conf as well as written a state but the event is not being generated and it seems like the trigger is not working

I am attaching my code files below

**/etc/salt/master/reactor.conf**

```
reactor:
  - 'os_family_changed':
    - /srv/salt/reactor/os_family_changed.sls
```

**/srv/salt/reactor/os_family_changed.sls:**

```
{% set old_os_family = grains['os_family'] %}
{% if grains['os_family'] != old_os_family %}
my_grain_changed:
  module.run:
    - name: state.apply
    - tgt: {{ data['id'] }}
    - arg:
      - test_os_family_changed.sls
{% endif %}
```

**test_os_family_changed.sls:**

```
test:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        echo 'hi' >> /tmp/test
```

> NOTE: I want to extend this usecase to be able to read grains from EC2 AWS metadata in future.

I am not sure how to achieve this or what I am missing, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```py
{% set old_os_family = grains['os_family'] %}
{% if grains['os_family'] != old_os_family %}
```

The check can never be true, because you set the two values to be equal.

You need to update `old_os_family` and store it somewhere persistent *after* performing the check.

---

Note also that grains are not expected to change, and thus are heavily cached. You may not see a change for up to days.

Comment: I agree, the logic seems off. Also as you are saying that I have to store it as a persistence then would I have to use a beacon to monitor it and then trigger a reactor? or is there any direct way without using a beacon?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You can use a beacon, or you can do what you are trying to but actually store the old value.